# Is it likely that RUF reports can be used to generate negative reputation for my server?

Tags: dmarc

I recently enabled RUF reports for those requesting them, and it occurred to me that if someone wanted to, they could force my server to generate a lot of RUF reports for various domains.

Assuming my server is configured correctly, is it likely that I would earn a negative reputation is someone targeted the server to force it to send excessive RUF reports?

Comment: What software do you use to send them?

Comment: @anx OpenDMARC and Postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, mail server operators will generally not punish you for sending them *failure reports* **they explicitly opted in to receive** - provided your volume and format matches reasonable expectations.

Any software designed with the *"obvious considerations"* listed in [RFC 7489 Section 7.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-7.3) in mind should limit the output to a fair level of traffic amplification. You are only forwarding about as much crap as was forwarded to you, which is not a particularly large increase for internet standards.

Whoever does not want *failure reports* (any more) can revoke his opt-in.

Note that sending *or* receiving *failure reports* is not exactly common these days - I suspect many share my opinion that it is simply not very useful beyond aggregate reports, and produces mostly unnecessary privacy concerns.

Comment: rua/ruf often are not even collected in the same place/department/company. There might not even be a direct feedback channel between the *receiving* mail servers and the people being alerted of unusual reports regarding *outgoing* mail.